# gRPC server launched from Tomcat thread

Tags: rest, tomcat, grpc

We have an application that provides a REST service that gets deployed within a Tomcat container. At startup, the application caches a lot of expensive objects (e.g., database connections, HSM connections, often read database objects, etc.) and then remains running for a long period of time. We would like to add a gRPC interface to the application's APIs so that clients can choose between the classic REST interface and gRPC.

Is it safe to have the current application running within Tomcat launch a gRPC server within the same application space? Our hope is that we can do this and share the cached objects instead of there being two applications (1. REST via Tomcat and 2. gRPC) with duplicate objects in memory. We are thinking we can have a separate thread launch the gRPC server to accept the requests and then make use of the same controllers that the current setup uses.

Comment: ever get an answer to this?